# Top-N using Python, MapReduce

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm using Python to write a MapReduce algorithm to find the top-10 viewed movies. I used two mappers and two reducers. The first mapper emit (movid, 1) and the first reducer outputs movid, frequency of occurrence (call it counter). I want to find the top-10 movie while keeping the code distributed. The attached image is my output (movid , count).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GRg7.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Better provide a [mre] with actual code and valid python objects.